# Xamarin MasterDetail page and UIDatePicker doesn't show

Tags: ios, xamarin, master-pages, uidatepicker

I'm creating empty project and adding master page there. 
If i add ios UIDatePicker to mainPage everything works, but on MasterDetailPage doesn't,  checked element from code on masterPage it is null.

this master detail page

```
<Grid>

        <ios:UIDatePicker x:Name="dp" />

</Grid>
```

and this usual main page

```
<Grid x:Name="content1">
        <ios:UIDatePicker x:Name="dp" />
</Grid>
```

just change
            MainPage = new App8.MainPage(); 
to
            MainPage = new App8.MasterDetailPage1(); 
in app.xaml.cs

Comment: Hi Salavat! When you get a chance, please edit your question, remove the link and add your code, because StackOverflow moderators will likely remove your question for only containing a link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution, add stacklayout to your xaml page,
and folowing code to cs file

```
 var dt = new UIDatePicker();
 UIView vw = new UIView();
 var fr = vw.Frame;
 fr.Width = 300f;
 fr.Height = 100f;
 vw.Frame = fr;
 dt.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, vw.Frame.Width,0);
 dt.ClipsToBounds=true;
 vw.AddSubview(dt);
 yourStackLayout.Children.Add(vw);
```